# String one of many strings from a URL

Tags: php

Two scenarios:

1. http://www.example.com/index.php
2. http://www.example.com/index.php?string1=foo&string2=foo2

Use case:

1. If scenario 1 is true, I need to add the string `?string1=foo`
2. If scenario 2 is true, I need to remove string2=foo2 and put in string3=foo3

The situation that I come to have problems with:

1. If there is already a string, I will need to add "&", otherwise it will just be "?".
2. I don't have a clue how to get the last string and be able to replace it.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should read about `regex`

Comment: @RicardoLohmann I don't think the OP needs `regex` in this case. :) Can be done using simple array manipulation. What say?

Comment: @PraveenKumar There're many ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

URL parameters are always in the `$_GET` array. You can use that to build your parameter list and then use `http_build_query` to create your URL query string.

```
$new_url_params = $_GET;
if ( count($new_url_params)==0 ) {
    $new_url_params['string1']='foo';
} else if ( isset($new_url_params['string2']) ) {
    unset($new_url_params['string2']);
    $new_url_params['string3'] = 'foo3';
}
$new_url = 'http://www.example.com/index.php?'.http_build_query($new_url_params);
```

I imagine you may be looking to do something a little more complicated. So you may want to look into `parse_url` to get the parts of a URL.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to `strpos` of the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` at the `?` and then determine whether I need to keep the `?` or add `&` followed by the string. When I needed to switch the last string, I did a `str_replace`. I dont't know if this is the best solution, but I was happy to get it to work....so far.